# MySQL - Using 'AS var_name' in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use a variable such as 'AS uniqueName' in the select in the same select later on?

I am trying to put some simple logic inside the select so I dont have to iterate through the result set just to do something easy:

```
SELECT
CASE emp_crns.ansi_class
    when -1 then 'N'
    when 150 then 0
    when 300 then 1
    when 600 then 2
    when 900 then 3
    when 1500 then 4
    when 2500 then 6
    when 3500 then 8
    else 'X'
end AS crnAnsiClassCode,
CONCAT('REV. ', crnAnsiClassCode, ' ', emp_models.name) AS modelName
FROM
emp_models
JOIN
emp_revisions ON emp_revisions.id=emp_models.revision_id
JOIN
emp_crns ON emp_crns.id=emp_revisions.crn_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sub-query to access the alias that you provided:

```
SELECT empcrns.crnAnsiClassCode,
    CONCAT('REV. ', empcrns.crnAnsiClassCode, ' ', emp_models.name) AS modelName
FROM emp_models
JOIN emp_revisions 
    ON emp_revisions.id=emp_models.revision_id
JOIN
(
    SELECT id, 
        CASE ansi_class
            when -1 then 'N'
            when 150 then 0
            when 300 then 1
            when 600 then 2
            when 900 then 3
            when 1500 then 4
            when 2500 then 6
            when 3500 then 8
            else 'X'
        end AS crnAnsiClassCode
    FROM emp_crns
) empcrns
    ON empcrns.id=emp_revisions.crn_id
```

Comment: Getting a `Unknown column 'emp_crns.id' in 'on clause'` on the last two lines?

Comment: Is there another way to do this? I am using activerecords in CodeIgniter and this functionality does not exist.

Comment: what functionality doesn't exist?

Comment: I am using activerecords so `$this->db->join(TABLE_NAME, CONDITION, JOIN_TYPE)` so i cannot fit this subquery inside the JOIN

Comment: @user1627928 I am not familiar with CodeIgniter and will be to answer that question.